# In Debian buster TLS 1.0 has been disabled, is it possible to enable TLS 1.0 for certain domains/ips only?

Tags: debian, ssl

I'm using the `python:3.8-slim-buster` docker image. Debian buster only allows TLS 1.2 or greater.
I need to make request for certain websites those only support TLS1.0, I want to be able to configure OpenSSL to allow requests using TLS 1.0 for only some domains/IP addresses, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that through system-wide configuration.

But individual applications *can* ask OpenSSL to select a different security level before they establish the TLS connection, e.g. by calling `SSL_CTX_set_security_level()` if written in C, or by including `@SECLEVEL=n` in their TLS cipher list. Similarly, they can select a different minimum TLS version.

For example, in Python this may work:

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1
ctx.set_ciphers("DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1")
```

Comment: You should be able to do it in a system-wide configuration, or rather openssl-install-wide configuration, by setting the `CipherString` (at the end of `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`).

Comment: it is completly different problem. for example any old app cannod make grather than TLSv1(v1.0), for example with communication with apache web server. How can I modify setting, allowing apache in debian buster accept TLSv1 / v1.1 ? Currently it accepts only TLSv1.2 / v1.3  . The same is with proftpd service and others enabled one. Recipe presesented above is applicable only for fresh apps, installed on deb. buster, or when I do my own build for apache, proftpd or similar using ssl layer.